Subscript alignment
My question is very genuine, yet I did not find any good answer to it. In the following math equation:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\|f\|_{U^{\frac{1}{2}}} + \|f\|_{U}$

\end{document}

it displays 
and one ca see that the "subscript alignment" is by default a "top" alignment, i.e. the top of the 1/2 in the first subscript aligns with the top of the U in the second subscript.
Is there an easy way to force alignment on the bottom so that the formula would be better looking (although this is a personal statement, I agree).

They do not look top aligned to me. (I would write 1/2 for the fraction.)

When placing the term in a first-level subscript position, I wouldn't write U^{\frac{1}{2}}. Instead, I'd write either U^{0.5} or U^{1/2}. That way, it becomes much easier or even unnecessary to perform vertical alignment vs. just _U.

Observe that because 1/2 has ever so slightly more height and depth than 0.5 does, it's necessary to insert a \vphantom when balancing \norm{f}_{U^{1/2}} and \norm{f}_{U}. In contrast, no vertical adjustment is needed for _{U^{0.5}}.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}

$\norm{f}_{U^{0.5}} + \norm{f}_{U}$ % no \vphantom needed
\qquad
$\norm{f}_{U^{1/2}} + \norm{f}_{U^{\vphantom{/}}}$ % need a \vphantom

\end{document}


Thank you very much! The \vphantom trick is a good one!
I actually prefer writing 1/2 as I did (and would probably not write 0.5 for esthetic reasons) so I'll go for the vphantom!

\vphantom is enough.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\|f\|_{U^{\frac{1}{2}}} + \|f\|_{U^{\vphantom{\frac12}}}$

\end{document}

